How to ensure terminal emulator exits when killing a tmux session?
I have the code below in my ~/.zshrc to create or attach to a tmux session named after the current terminal emulator. It works as intended in most cases, but I'm encountering an issue when I attach to a detached session.
if [ -z "$TMUX" ]; then
  SESH=$(ps -p $PPID -o comm=)
  if ! tmux has-session -t "$SESH" 2>/dev/null; then
    tmux new-session -s "$SESH"
  else
    tmux attach-session -t "$SESH"
  fi
  if ! tmux has-session -t "$SESH" 2>/dev/null; then
    exit
  fi
fi

When I run kill-session or manually close all windows, the terminal emulator exits.
When I detach from the session, terminal emulator remains open.
However, When I attach to a detached session and then run kill-session or manually close all windows, the terminal emulator does not exit; only the tmux session is exited.
How can I modify that code to ensure that the terminal emulator exits when I kill the tmux session after attaching to it?
Here is my .tmux.conf for reference, but I don't think that would be relevant to this behaviour.
Executing typeset -p TMUX SESH; tmux has-session -t "$SESH"; echo $? on the shell that should have been exited gives
typeset: no such variable: TMUX typeset 
SESH=wezterm-gui no server running on /tmp/tmux-1000/default 
1

while executing list-sessions outputs
no server running on /tmp/tmux-1000/default


That script is just a part of my .zshrc file. source. My .tmux.conf but I don't think that would be relevant to this behaviour

I can't reproduce here. That if ! tmux has-session -t "$SESH" 2>/dev/null; then exit; fi should ensure zsh exits along with the terminal that hosts it when there are no session named $SESH left. What's the output of typeset -p TMUX SESH; tmux has-session -t "$SESH"; echo $? if run in that shell that should have exited but didn't?

Output of typeset -p TMUX SESH; tmux has-session -t "$SESH"; echo $?  is
typeset: no such variable: TMUX typeset SESH=wezterm-gui no server running on /tmp/tmux-1000/default 1 on the shell that should have been exited.
However. executing list-sessions gives no server running on /tmp/tmux-1000/default

You could add a tmux list-sessions call in the .zshrc before the if ! .... Could be the tmux attach-session returns in your case before the session is not fully torn down yet. Maybe adding a sleep 0.2 after the tmux attach-session -t "$SESH" would help.

Better approaches might be:
Either a) exec tmux, fully replacing the shell process with the tmux process; once tmux exits, there is nothing more to return to, so the terminal will close.
Or b) add the -P option to your tmux detach-client keybind, so that it sends a SIGHUP to the parent shell. (No equivalent for kill-session.)

I want to keep the terminal when the session is detached, only exit when it killed. Using approach a) closes the terminal when the session is detached.
